Make the element sticky untill the scroll driven animation is finished
Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

-when the elements become visible to the user, the scroll-driven rotate animation starts on them one-by-one,and all 3 elements become sticky (meaning that they do not disappear while the user is scrolling down) until the animation on the last one is finished.
-when the animation is finished, the page returns to its normal behavior
Executable code:
This code doesn't make the elements sticky when needed.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.animation');
  let delay = 0;

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        entry.target.style.animationDelay = `${delay}s`;
        entry.target.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
        console.log('running');

        // Add sticky class when the element is in view
        entry.target.classList.add('sticky');

        delay += 2.5; // Increase delay for the next element
        observer.unobserve(entry.target); // Stop observing once the animation is triggered
      }
    });
  }, {
    threshold: 0.5
  }); // Trigger when 50% of the element is in view

  elements.forEach(element => {
    console.log('paused');
    element.style.animationPlayState = 'paused'; // Pause animation until triggered
    observer.observe(element);

    // Remove sticky class after the animation ends
    element.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
      console.log('animationend')
      element.classList.remove('sticky');
    });
  });
});
.content {
  width: 75%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p,
h1 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.animation {
  view-timeline: --subjectReveal block;
  animation-timeline: --subjectReveal;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: bisque;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-name: mymove;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  position: relative;
  /* Normal position */
}

.animation:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--subjectReveal) * 1);
}

.animation:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--subjectReveal) * 2);
}

.animation:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--subjectReveal) * 3);
}


/* Define the sticky behavior */

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
  /* Adjust top as needed */
  z-index: 10;
  /* Ensure it stays on top */
}

@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}




.as-console-wrapper { height:50px; }
Scroll this
<div style="height:1000px; min-height: 300px; max-width: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">
  <div class="animation"></div>
  <div class="animation"></div>
  <div class="animation"></div>
</div>




It's an animation that occurs only when scrolling, but the current code doesn't seem to have space for scrolling. Should I arbitrarily increase the height and reproduce it?

@NINE I added only the html part with the elements to which the animation is applied.

I changed your CSS (<div style="height:1000px;) slightly to show the effect and limited the height of the snippet console

@mplungjan thanks for clarifying my code! any ideas on how to implement what is shown in the gif?

Can you please first of all clarify, how exactly you want this to behave. Your animated image suggests that the rotate animation would start when the elements reached the middle of the screen, but in your code it says, // Trigger when 50% of the element is in view. And your sticky class has top: 10px;, which means the elements would only get sticky, when they are less than 10px from the top of the scrollable container - that also doesn't appear to match, what you actually want to achieve.

// Remove sticky class after the animation ends - your image suggests you want them all to become sticky, and then unstuck again, at the same time. But your animations will end at different times, due to the different initial delays - so you should not remove the class from each individual element when its own animation has ended; but remove it from all of them, when the animation on the last element has finished.

You have already defined the animation-delay in your CSS - not sure why you'd need to set it again in your JS part then? Would it not make much more sense, if you just observed one of those elements for intersection (since they are all on the same position on the y axis anyway), then triggered the animation for all of them (for example by simply giving the container element a class) - with the delays already set in the CSS?

Would you like to try this?
I used CSS animation-range-start, It was in the code you provided..
but it seems difficult to support it on Firefox and Safari because it's an experimental function.
I've worked on the movements you want, so use the parts you can refer to!
I hope it helps :)


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const elementsContent = document.querySelector('.animation-content');
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.animation');

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        elements.forEach((element) => {
          element.style.animationName = 'mymove'; // add animation to div
          element.style.animationPlayState = 'running'; // Start animation
        });
        observer.unobserve(entry.target); // Stop observing
      }
    });
  }, {
    threshold: 0.8
  }); // Trigger when 80% of the element is in view

  observer.observe(elementsContent);
});
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2vw;
  background: #222;
}

.animation-wrap {
  height: 300vh;
  background: #fff;
}

.animation-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.animation {
  view-timeline: --subjectReveal block;
  animation-timeline: --subjectReveal;
  animation-range-start: entry 200%;
  height: 0; /* ignore this, just for square */
  width: 20vw; /* ignore this, just for square */
  padding-bottom:20vw; /* ignore this, just for square */
  background-color: bisque;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*whenendanimation,holdstartstate*/
  animation-play-state: paused;
  /*pausedatfirst*/
  position: relative;
  /*Normalposition*/
}

.animation:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.animation:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
}

.animation:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 2.8s;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

div[class*="other-content"] {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.other-content_01 {
  height: 400px;
  background: #eee;
}

.other-content_02 {
  height: 1000px;
  background: #ddd;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="other-content_01">
    Scroll Page :)
  </div>
  <div class="animation-wrap">
    <div class="animation-content">
      <div class="animation"></div>
      <div class="animation"></div>
      <div class="animation"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="other-content_02">
    Thank you!
  </div>

  <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>




Thanks a lot, that's what I was trying to achieve :)
